# How to relate the valuation of x/y (For a minimal Weierstrass equation)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I'm reading an article about elliptic curves, but since I'm not very experienced on this subject, I ended up getting stuck. The problem starts as:

"Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a number field and $E/K$ an elliptic curve defined over $K$. Let $v\in M_K$ be a finite place of good reduction for $E$, and fix a minimal Weierstrass equation for $E$ at $v$,
$$y^2+a_1xy+a_3y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6$$
Then..."

After this there are some equations concerning the local canonical height which the article wants to prove, but the problem I have is not really about this equations. Its all about the following statement made during the proof:

$``$ The integrality of the Weierstrass equation implies EASILY that
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
v(x^{-1})<0 \iff v(x/y)<0   \quad"
\end{equation}

After playing with the Weierstrass equation and it's integrality ($v(a_i)\ge 0$ for all the $i$'s), indeed I was able to conclude

$$v(x)<0 \iff v(y)<0 \quad\text{and in this case }\quad 2v(y)=3v(x)$$
Thus $$v(x)<0 \Rightarrow v(y/x)<0$$
Hence $$v(x/y)\le0 \Rightarrow v(x^{-1})\le0$$

But this was the closest I could get to the statement $(1)$. I have already tried (without success) to work on the Weierstrass equation in a lots of different ways to explicit the $(x/y)$ and somehow manage to relate $v(x/y)$ and $v(x^{-1})$ as expected in $(1)$.

At this point, due to the "easily" on the text and since I'm not very experienced, I'm starting to think it is some kind of standard trick or I'm missing something very obvious. I would appreciate so much any kind of help.

I'm sorry for my English, it is not my native language.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y$ is a unit, then (1) says $v(x^{-1})<0$ iff $v(x) < 0$ which is a contradiction unless $v(x)=0$.  So we can look for counterexample by finding a point where $v(y)=0$ but $v(x) \ne 0$.

Consider the curve $y^2=x^3-4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Its discriminant is $-2^8 3^3$, hence it is a global minimal Weierstrass equation (no prime in the discriminant occurs with multiplicity $\ge 12$ - see Silverman *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, Chapter VII, section 1).  Take the point $x=5$, $y=11$, and valuation $v$ at the prime 5, which is a prime of good reduction for this curve.  Then $v(y)=0$, $v(x)=1$, and we have our counterexample. In fact, $v(x^{-1}) = v(1/5) = -1$ but $v(x/y) = v(5/11) = 1$.

Comment: Sorry but I don't got it very well. If $v(y)=0$, from what you wrote we can conclude that $v(x)$ can not be lower or greater than $0$ (since this would lead to a contradiction). But we could still have $v(x)=0$ without any problems in this case isn't it? And even if $v(y)=0$ led us to a contradiction, this would only prove the equation has no solution with $v(y)=0$. Am I wrong? Sorry if I'm completely misunderstanding something.

Comment: You're right that I didn't consider the case $v(x)=0$.  I added some clarifications and an explicit counterexample.

Comment: Well pointed, thanks a lot! So this section of the article is in some sense just wrong, cuz the whole proof relies on this. Now with this counterexample in mind, I could even produce an other counterexample to one of the statements in this section's Theorems. Luckily enough, I think this section is not really a key point to the Main Theorem of the article. Thanks again!!